# APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS XMLHTTPREQUEST

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to create a progress bar with `xmlhttprequest` and i was thinking this is a good way without using a form, because I need the `xmlhttp.responseText`.

Why doesn't this work?

```
formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("picture",  document.getElementById('picture').files[0]);
formdata.append("APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS",  "2");
xmlhttp.open( "POST", 'upload.php', true );
xmlhttp.send(formdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes:

Replace

```
xmlhttp.open( "POST", upload.php, true );
```

with

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", 'upload.php', true);
```